# База данных в Access, уже открыта или нет?

Tags: c#, ms-access

Есть клиент для связи и редактирования базы, как узнать, открыта ли она уже другим пользователем на другом компьютере? 
Пока сам заметил, что создается временный файл, .laccdb или .ldb для .accdb и .mdb соответственно, то есть можно проверить существование этого файла. Но есть ли другой способ? потому как эти временные файлы, бывает, долго остаются в папке.

Comment: Наличие файла блокировок ни о чём не говорит. Попробуйте подключиться к БД в монопольном режиме - если она уже кем-то используется, то не получится...

Answer (score 1):

Второй вариант:

```html
OleDbConnection con; 
 
            try
            {    
                Console.WriteLine ("Создание новое соединение");
                con =new OleDbConnection("Provider=LCPI.IBProvider;");
                Console.WriteLine("Попытка открытое соединение");
                con.Open();
                 
                Console.WriteLine("Закрыть соединение, если состояние соединения открыт");        
                if (con.State  == ConnectionState.Open)
                   {con.Close();}
            }    
            catch(OleDbException myOLEDBException)
            { 
                Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                    for (int i = 0; i<=myOLEDBException.Errors.Count-1;i++)
                    {
                    Console.WriteLine("Сообщение " + (i + 1) + ": " + myOLEDBException.Errors[i].Message);
                    Console.WriteLine("локалние: " + myOLEDBException.Errors[i].NativeError.ToString());
                    Console.WriteLine("Source: " + myOLEDBException.Errors[i].Source);
                    Console.WriteLine("SQL: " + myOLEDBException.Errors[i].SQLState);
                    Console.WriteLine("----------------------------------------");
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Существование файла можно проверит с помужю функция File.Exits**:

```html
if (File.Exists("имя файла"))
        {
            //.....
        }
```